# Парсинг сайта написанного на Битрикс

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, cookie, request

Пытаюсь парсить данные с сайта https://moba.ru. В панели разработчика заметил, что при переходе по этому адресе происходит перенаправление на него же:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На второй странице вся нужная мне информация. В первом ответе приходит два скрипта:

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

один из которых, как я понял, рисует экран загрузки.
Также в первом ответе есть такие заголовки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во втором запросе, ответ на который со статус-кодом двести, в заголовках запроса похожая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если в коде я requests.get вставляю эти Cookie (из 2-го ответа), то запросы работают и я получаю искомую html страницу. Но эти куки часто обновляются. Я пытался забрать куки из редиректа и сделать запрос с ними, но, как видно из скриншотов ниже, там не хватает полей BITRIX_SM_mb_h, BITRIX_SM_mb_key, BITRIX_SM_mb_key2.
Возможно, оставшиеся куки как-то генерируются с помощью скрипта, я не уверен. С помощью Selenium все работает, но, как я понял, это достаточно дорогостоящее по времени решение, я же хочу минимизировать время на парсинг, тк пытаюсь сделать Веб-API.
Могу я как-то, с помощью библиотеки requests получит желанную информацию?